# How to split phrase into word and display corresponding image in each word?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've already tried this codes below but it only reads word not a phrase and this codes worked and didn't meet what I want.Each word that the user input it will only add and add to an empty array-list. What I want to achieve is when an user input a phrase it will split by space and store in an empty array-list. That array-list will compare to another array-list that contains words when the condition is true it will display a corresponding image and will now read the next word in the phrase.

```
 private List<String> wordsList;
private ArrayList<String>wordsToDisplay=new ArrayList<>();
boolean missingGIF;
int counter;
```

wordsList= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sample)));

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String input = editText.getText().toString();
            String[]splited = input.split("//s+");
            int count = splited.length;

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){

                String word = splited[i];

                if(wordsList.contains(word)){
                    wordsToDisplay.add(splited[i]);
                }
                    else
                        missingGIF = true;
            }
        sample();

        }
    });
}
```

This is the sample method.

```
if(wordsToDisplay.size()>0){

        counter=0;

        gifImageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(wordsToDisplay.get(0),"drawable",getPackageName()));

        animation = (GifDrawable)gifImageView.getDrawable();
        resetAnimation();
        startAnimation();

    animation.addAnimationListener(this);
```

}

And this is my animation listener which display corresponding images in all the words that have been inputted by the user.

```
@Override
public void onAnimationCompleted(int loopNumber) {

    if(wordsToDisplay.size()>1){

        if(counter<wordsToDisplay.size()){


            try{

                counter++;

                gifImageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(wordsToDisplay.get(counter),"drawable",getPackageName()));
                animation = (GifDrawable)gifImageView.getDrawable();
                resetAnimation();
                startAnimation();
                animation.addAnimationListener(this);




            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                Log.d("Expected",e.toString());
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `counter` and use below logic

```
@Override
public void onAnimationCompleted(int loopNumber) {

    if(!wordsToDisplay.isEmpty()){
        String nextWord = wordsToDisplay.remove(0);
        gifImageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(nextWord,"drawable",getPackageName()));
        animation = (GifDrawable)gifImageView.getDrawable();
        resetAnimation();
        startAnimation();
        animation.addAnimationListener(this); 
    }
}
```